# Error "Invalid entry Id/Uri" for batch updates to google contacts

Tags: gdata, google-contacts-api

I'm attempting to perform a batch update of google contacts per https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#batch_operations_for_contacts, but I'm getting an "Invalid entry Id/Uri" error. I'm posting the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:batch="http://schemas.google.com/gdata/batch" xmlns:gContact="http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008" xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005" xmlns:openSearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/" gd:etag="&quot;RHwzfzVSLyt7I2A9XRVREk4DQQw.&quot;">
  <entry gd:etag="&quot;Q34zcDVSLit7I2A9XRVTFkkOTwE.&quot;">
    <id>http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/emiliano.heyns%40iris-advies.com/base/376125d892c1b5a</id>
    <batch:id>delete-cornel.straver@han.nl</batch:id>
    <batch:operation type="delete"/>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

to which I'm getting this response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:openSearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/" xmlns:batch="http://schemas.google.com/gdata/batch" xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005" xmlns:gContact="http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008">
  <id>https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/emiliano.heyns%40iris-advies.com/full/batch/1432240618884</id>
  <updated>2015-05-21T20:36:58.884Z</updated>
  <title>Batch Feed</title>
  <entry>
    <id>http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/emiliano.heyns%40iris-advies.com/base/376125d892c1b5a</id>
    <updated>2015-05-21T20:36:58.884Z</updated>
    <title>Error</title>
    <content>Invalid entry Id/Uri</content>
    <batch:id>delete-cornel.straver@han.nl</batch:id>
    <batch:status code="400" reason="Invalid entry Id/Uri"/>
    <batch:operation type="delete"/>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

I know the etags and the ID are correct as I've gotten them by requesting the contacts feed; it's the response from that which I'm modyfying into the query above.

Comment: In the request, emiliano.heyns%40iris-advies.com is this useremail? check these links https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2126